# CPU Boost when starting pods in GKE Autopilot?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We're looking to migrate our standard GKE cluster to [autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview), but several pods that we have doesn't require much CPU/memory after they started up. However, during startup, we would like some pods to get more CPU so that they start faster. For example, consider this pod:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-pod
  labels:
    name: my-pod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: my-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: my-pod
        version: "1.0.0"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-pod
          image: "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-repo/my-pod:1.0.0"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
...
```

This pod could take 2-3 minutes to start up. If we change CPU to 2000m, it starts *much* faster. But this pod is long-running, and it's unnecessary for us to pay for 2000m when 500m (or less) is required once it's up and running. I'm looking for something similar to [Cloud Run Startup Boost](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu#startup-boost) but for GKE Autopilot.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Did you try to add this?
          resources:
           limits:
               cpu: 1
            requests:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "500m"

It will manage burst to 1 CPU.
I know that it's not a fully compliant solution to your problem but could be a pragmatic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Kubernetes itself doesn't have this feature.

Maybe you should look for ways to optimise the startup time of the container itself.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to push needed work into a startup container?

You can tune the resource requests for the startup container higher, so have it do the startup work and serialize output somewhere on disk (or in /tmp), then have your runtime container take over with lower limits.